# Python Selenium get list of URLs from file

Tags: python, html, selenium

I basically want to scrape multiple urls that are stored in a csv file and return results for each.

```
ips = "C:/Projects/file.csv"
cpes = open (ips, 'r')
cpes.seek(0)

#Assign prefix and suffix to ip in each line
for lines in cpes.readlines():
    ip = lines.strip()
    urls = 'https://' + ip
    overview = 'https://' + ip + '/overview.asp'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() #Enable Chrome driver options
options.add_argument('headless') #No browser is opened to view process
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging']) #Disable Devtools log message
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
for url in urls:
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
    password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
    username.send_keys(credentials.usrn)
    password.send_keys(credentials.pswd, Keys.ENTER)
    browser.get(overview)
    source = browser.page_source
```

The output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cpe3.py", line 28, in <module>
    browser.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\duane.barker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\duane.barker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\duane.barker\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are setting the variables: `urls` and `overview` to **`string`** types. I believe you are trying to create a list of each, and use those in your loop for navigating pages, try this:

```
#Assign prefix and suffix to ip in each line
urls = []
overviews = []
for lines in cpes.readlines():
    ip = lines.strip()
    urls.append('https://' + ip)
    overviews.append('https://' + ip + '/overview.asp')
```

That way, when you go to loop over `urls`, `url` will be a full URL instead of the first letter of the last string. ie `h` from `https://`. You need to make these changes to your loop as well:

```
for url, overview in zip(urls, overviews):
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
    password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
    username.send_keys(credentials.usrn)
    password.send_keys(credentials.pswd, Keys.ENTER)
    browser.get(overview)
    source = browser.page_source
```

This should alleviate your error when trying to navigate using the `.get()` method, since you are now traveling to an actual page.

Comment: Please forgive my "noobness", but I seemed to have reached another snag. The URLs are dynamically assigned IP address and some of them can't be reachable. How do i try a url, if reachable, run rest of the code but if unreachable, skip to next IP?

Comment: It appears you have a new error with not reaching certain IPs, please create a new question with more information regarding the new error and I can address it